# Provide a descriptive label for a skos:semanticRelation

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

When using the skos vocabulary, is it possible to provide a descriptive label to describe a relationship between two concepts.  for example you can have two concepts linked by skos:related but hwo do you say exactly how they are related.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `skos:note` (from [SKOS Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/skos-primer/#secdocumentation)) or one of the specialised predicates that are subproperties of this might do what you want.

You can't introduce a Blank Node and hang an `rdfs:label` of it like you might do in general RDF data modelling since `skos:related` is not transitive i.e.

```
:a skos:related :b .
:b skos:related :c .
```

Only says that `:a` is related to `:b` and `:b` is related to `:c` and **does not** imply that `:a` is related to `:c`

Best way to do it might be to define your own predicate which is a subproperty of `skos:related` and apply relevant labels, comments and descriptions to that.  **BUT** if you do this you'll need to be using tools that can do inference as SKOS tools won't be aware of your property automatically e.g.

```
ex:myRelation rdf:type rdf:Property ;
              rdfs:label "My Relation" ;
              rdfs:comment "Detailed description of the relation..." .

:a ex:myRelation :b .
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  Its exactly what I am trying to do with one exception, the description is dynamic i.e neither a nor b or the relationship between them exist until they are created by the user.  Therefore the user creates both and a and b and then describes the relationship between them in the form of a string.